# Information On My Form Not Sending To Me PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

I have a reservation form on my website, and when someone clicks 'submit', a different random number comes up every time.

Just a few days ago, when the form gets e-mailed back to me, I saw the reservation number that came up for my customer.

But now it's not and I can't figure out way.

This is the  version

```
     <?php

     $rando=trim($_POST['lblrand']);

     <tr>
  <td align='left'><strong> Form  Registration No: </strong> </td>
  <td>".$rando."</td>
  </tr>
```

Then this is the HTML5 coding:

```
       <script> 

    // wait for the DOM to be loaded 

    $(document).ready(function() { 
        var ranval = Math.floor((Math.random()*10000)+1);
            $('input[name=lblrand]').val(ranval);
        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
        $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() {   
            alert("Your Message has been sent!Your Form Registration Number is: "+ ranval); 
            $('#myForm').resetForm(); 
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

I want to know what went wrong for it to all of a sudden stop working.

Any help/advice would be useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should not rely on javascript for your registration number as it can be manipulated by the client.

Perhaps in this case javascript was simply disabled and the form was sent in the conventional way.

You should generate the number on the server side and check on form submit as well if it has been submitted with the rest of the form. You can add it to the form for example as a hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

Missed to add `echo "`

```
<?php

 $rando=trim($_POST['lblrand']);

 echo "<tr>
  <td align='left'><strong> Form  Registration No: </strong> </td>
  <td>".$rando."</td>
</tr>";
```